# Magento : Module With an Input to Database

Tags: magento-1.9, database, delivery-time

I am creating module that would display estimated delivery time.

I want to have a section in admin panel under "system"->"configuration" for my module that would contain seven input fields (one for each day of week), similar to this: [image]

The data should be stored in a database table.

I've tried searching for way to do this, but I couldn't find tutorials doing exactly this, and since i'm relatively new to Magento, I don't really know what needs to be changed.

Comment: If you want to add fields in `System > Configuration` then you don't need to create table or write code. Magento will automatically save data of `System > Configuration` fields to `core_config_data` table with its path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add custom section In system configuration, you have to create a Magento module, you can create by following below steps,

- Where `Vendor_Module` is you module (`Vendor` is your company name and `Module` is your module name, you can write whatever you want)

`app/etc/modules/Vendor_Module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Vendor_Module>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </Vendor_Module>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

create a new directory in `local`(app>code>local) with `Vendor` and `Module`, so It should like this, and create a new `config.xml`

```
app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Module>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Vendor_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <class>Vendor_Module_Helper</class>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

now, create `system.xml` in `etc` directory, like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <shippinginfo translate="label" module="module">
            <label>YOUR_LABEL</label>
            <tab>general</tab>
            <sort_order>60</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>                    
                <shipping_times>
                    <fields>
                        <monday translate="label">
                            <label>Monday</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <comment>e.g 17.00</comment>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </monday>
                        <tuesday translate="label">
                            <label>Tuesday</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <comment>e.g 17.00</comment>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </tuesday>
                        <wednesday translate="label">
                            <label>Wednesday</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <comment>e.g 17.00</comment>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </wednesday>
                        <thursday translate="label">
                            <label>Thursday</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <comment>e.g 17.00</comment>
                            <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </thursday>
                        <friday translate="label">
                            <label>Friday</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <comment>e.g 17.00</comment>
                            <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </friday>
                        <saturday translate="label">
                            <label>Saturday</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <comment>Leave blank If its non shipping day</comment>
                            <sort_order>60</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </saturday>
                        <sunday translate="label">
                            <label>Sunday</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <comment>Leave blank If its non shipping day</comment>
                            <sort_order>70</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </sunday>                           
                    </fields>
                </shipping_times>
            </groups>
        </shippinginfo>
    </section>
</config>
```

now create a `helper` `class` in `helper` directory, like this

```
<?php

class Vendor_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

refresh your cache, and check

And you don't need to save this value, Magento will manage this and you can get save value by using

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('shippinginfo/shipping_times/monday');
```

Comment: Hmmm, I did everything like you said, but I don't see the new section in the system->configurations. The module is working, I checked in the advanced settings. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: please refresh your cache, still If its not working then please post your full code here @JurģisTomsLiepiņš

Comment: Sorry, I finally got back to trying this, but this does not seem to work. I copied all of the code as it is, didnt even change the module names. I refreshed my cache, but I still don't see "YOUR_LABEL" in the "general" tab. Can you suggest what might be wrong?